# Fixed position of responsive element in desktop mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have an ecommerce one-pager that has about 12 items on Bootstrap. In mobile mode, I append the checkout at the bottom of the list. In desktop mode, I break it out into a separate column as shown below. The issue is, if I scroll down, the checkout disappears. I want to fix position it to scroll with the page. I was looking at Bootstraps affix attribue:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">...</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me what I can add to the below code to fix position for desktop only mode?

```
<div class="row" class="visible-desktop">
  <div class="span7" class="visible-desktop">
    <div class="menu-container">
      Column 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="span5" class="visible-desktop">
    <div class="checkout">
      Checkout that breaks out to second column if desktop
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using latest version of Bootstrap .visible-desktop class is changed to .visible-md .visible-lg, check it out

Comment: I should have mentioned that i'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this, add a media query for Desktops. 
If you're using bootstrap, the desktop mode is above 979px;

```
@media (min-width:979px) {
  .checkout {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0; 
    right:0; 
    z-index:100;

  }
}
```

Ofcourse change sizes, and position to suit your needs.

This is reference page for sizes, bootstrap 2.3.2 docs http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html